# How to force git to remerge a commit it thinks is already merged

Tags: git, merge, branch

I have three branches, `master`, `feature`, and `integration`. `integration` represents the software configuration deployed to a specific development server. Feature branches are first merged into an `integration` branch, tested on the corresponding server, and then merged into `master`.

```
                \          \
o----------------o----------o             (master)
    \    \                              
     \    o----o-------o--o---o----o      (integration)
      \       /       /      /    /   
       o-----o-------o--o---o----o--o     (feature)
```

My goal is to update my `integration` branch to be identical to `master`, and then merge my `feature` branch into it so that the `integration` branch is the `master` branch plus the changes in my `feature` branch.

To do this first merged my `integration` branch into master with `strategy=ours` and then I fast-forwarded the `integration` branch to be the same as the `master` branch.

```
                \          \
o----------------o----------o--------X           (master, integration)
    \    \                          /    
     \    o----o-------o--o---o----o             
      \       /       /      /    /   
       o-----o-------o--o---o----o--o            (feature)
```

And then my plan was to merge the `feature` branch into the newly updated `integration` branch.

```
                \          \
o----------------o----------o--------X-           (master)
    \    \                          / \ 
     \    o----o-------o--o---o----o   Y          (integration)
      \       /       /      /    /   /   
       o-----o---o---o--o---o----o---o          (feature)
```

However, when I do that my updated `integration` branch is identical to the previous commit on the integration branch, e.g. X and Y are identical, instead of being the sum of the `master` branch plus my changes in the feature branch.

So, can anyone recommend a way for me to get the branches configured in the way I want them?

Comment: Why not merge master into feature directly?

Comment: Philosophically because I want to re-baseline the server represented by the Integration branch to be identical to master. 

Practically because I'm already at the 2nd configuration shown so merging either master or integration into feature is the same operation. If I reset feature to the 2nd-to-last commit on it's branch then merge just fast-forwards. If I commit from the last commit on that branch then I just get the delta between the last two commits -- which is nothing bc the last commit was a "git commit --allow-empty" commit.

And the "X" commit has been pushed so I can't reset that.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused about what your history looks like and what you want to do. If you merge `integration` into `master`, only `master` should go forward, `integration` is not affected.

Comment: Between the first two examples shown I merged `integration` into `master`, which moved `master` forward as you said. That merge used the `ours` strategy so the new commit, X, is identical to the previous commit to `master`. Then I merged `master` into `integration` which fast-forwarded `integration` to the same commit, X, as `master`. That's the second diagram. Now I want to merge `master` into my `feature` branch so that all of the other work that's gone into `master` is incorporated in my branch. But git treats the merge as a fast-forward so I lose my changes to the `integration` branch.

Comment: In *To do this first merged my feature branch into master with strategy=ours and then I fast-forwarded the feature branch to be the same as the master branch.* I think you mean "merged `integration` into `master`" and "fast-forwarded `integration`", based on the diagram. (And it seems to be what you said in comments.)

Comment: Yes, you are correct. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

[Edit: fixed in question, strike-out in answer now] <s>Aside from the slight glitch in the question (the diagram shows the effect of `git checkout master && git merge -s ours integration && git checkout integration && git merge --ff-only master`, which uses `integration` everywhere that you said `feature`),</s> Git seems to be behaving the way Git is supposed to.

> My goal is to update my integration branch to be identical to master, and then merge my feature branch into it so that the integration branch is the master branch plus the changes in my feature branch.

This is not necessarily a good idea, because Git doesn't do merges the way I think you think it does merges. :-)

What `git merge` does is complicated because it's full of tiny details, but the *way* it does it is simple enough, and the graphs you have drawn here are a great start.  Let's start with the "before" one.  I will modify it just a tiny bit to add the `HEAD` notation and to pick out three commits, `L`, `R`, and `B`:

```
                \          \
B----------------o----------L         <-- master (HEAD)
    \    \
     \    o----o-------o--o---o----R   <-- integration
      \       /       /      /    /
       o-----o-------o--o---o----o--o   <-- feature
```

Each merge *strategy* (`-s recursive` being the default, and the `-s ours` that you used being another one) has total control over what happens next.  But let's assume, for a moment, that you run `git merge -s recursive integration` rather than `git merge -s ours integration`.  The first step of this merge strategy would be to locate the *merge base* commit.  Git does this by walking the graph backwards (in the direction of all the internal arrows, which always point backwards) to find the common ancestor between the current branch's tip commit and the named branch's tip commit.

The current branch is `HEAD` which is `master` which locates commit `L` (L here stands for Left, Local, or `--ours`).  The named commit is `integration` which locates commit `R` (R stands for Right, Remote, otheR, or `--theirs`).  `B`, the merge base, is the first shared commit we (or Git) will find if we walk the graph backwards simultaneously from both `L` and `R`.

So now, in an ordinary merge, Git would run the equivalent of:

```
git diff --find-renames B L > /tmp/left
git diff --find-renames B R > /tmp/right
```

It would then do its best to compute a new set of files that take the union of the two change-sets found in /tmp/left and /tmp/right and apply those to the files in `B`.

If all goes well, Git would then make a new commit with two parents, `L` first and then `R`, using the merged files.  This is in fact the new graph you get:

```
                \          \
o----------------o----------L--------X   <-- master (HEAD)
    \    \                          /
     \    o----o-------o--o---o----o   <-- integration
      \       /       /      /    /
       o-----o-------o--o---o----o--o   <-- feature
```

(I've un-named `B` and `R` as they are no longer special, but left `L` for just a moment.)  But you used `-s ours`, and this strategy doesn't actually run `git diff` at all.  It just uses the same tree as the previous commit, i.e., `L` itself.  So commits `L` and `X` represent the same *source* ... but not the same *commit history*, as now `integration` has been merged into `master`, throwing away any difference that *would have been introduced* in the process.

#### This is where it all goes wrong

Inasmuch as anything in Git has "meaning"—Git just follows a set of programmed procedures, so the only meaning is that we assign to it, or the ideas we use when we write these programmed procedures—the "meaning" of `-s ours` is: *everything in the branch I just merged is terrible; never use it again.*  The intent, as it were, is to kill off the branch.

Let's see how this works now when we run `git checkout integration && git merge --ff-only master` (or the same without the `--ff-only`, by default, if we have not messed with various Git configuration variables).  A fast-forward operation, which is not actually a merge at all, just moves a branch label.  The `git checkout` step alters our `HEAD` to point to `integration` so that it's `integration` that gets moved.  This results in your second graph:

```
                \          \
o----------------o----------o--------X   <-- master, integration (HEAD)
    \    \                          /
     \    o----o-------o--o---o----o
      \       /       /      /    /
       o-----o-------o--o---o----o--o   <-- feature
```

Now we might run `git merge feature` (with or without an explicit `-s recursive`).  That will walk the graph to find the merge base, which is the first commit reachable from both `X` and the tip of `feature`.  Starting from `X`, we move down-and-left twice to arrive at this:

```
                \          \
o----------------o----------o--------X   <-- master, integration (HEAD)
    \    \                          /
     \    o----o-------o--o---o----I
      \       /       /      /    /
       o-----o-------o--o---o----B--R   <-- feature
```

I've labeled the base and right-side commits again, but kept the left-side commit named `X`.  I've added one more single letter, `I`, which is the *old* tip of `integration`, before it got forwarded.

Now Git will run:

```
git diff --find-renames B X
git diff --find-renames B R
```

and combine the changes.

The change from `B` to `X` is: *throw away most of the stuff that was on `integration`*, which is obvious enough because the change from `I` to `X` is *throw away everything that was done on `integration`—go back to what was in `master`.*

We *might*, depending on `I` vs `X`, get to keep whatever happened from `B` to `I`.  We definitely keep whatever happened from `B` to `R`, unless it conflicts with the `B`-to-`X` changes.  These combined changes, `B` to `X` plus `B` to `R`, form the merge result, and if all seems well, Git makes your merge commit `Y` with first-parent `X` and second-parent `R`.

#### You can't get there from here (easily)

The big problem is the `git merge -s ours`, which records *that the merge happened*, but uses the *tree* (source code) from `master` only.  The later merge uses the recorded previous merge to find a new, better, simpler merge base ... and working from that merge base demonstrates that when merging `feature`, it's important to *un*-do (from that base) all the changes that had been on `integration`, as apparently they were terrible and should be thrown out.

It *is* actually possible to construct a different tree: you can run `git merge --no-commit`, which performs the tree-merging (diff combining) work and sets everything up so that the next `git commit` will make a merge commit, with the usual two parents, without actually making that commit yet.  Next, you can make whatever changes you like to the work-tree and `git add` the resulting files back into the index.  For instance, you could run `git diff <hash-of-X> <hash-of-I> | git apply`, to yank all those un-done changes right back into the work-tree.  (This assumes they will apply well.  Add `--full-index` to the diff and `-3` to the apply to get full three-way merging if needed.  I don't think Git will be able to deal well with renames here.)

In the end, though, you're working against the design: the behavior of merging, with newly computed merge bases after previous merges, is designed to work well as long as you don't use `-s ours`.  If you do use `-s ours`, it's probably meant to "kill off" a branch, not to keep working with it, and the merge base algorithm behaves that way.

Comment: The intent of the `ours` merge make the integration branch exactly identical to master. If there's a better way to do that I'd like to know.

Comment: Well, the obvious question is then: *Why do you care if the integration branch matches the master branch temporarily?* Still, you *can* make it this way, without using `git merge` at all, so that there's no merge recorded.

Comment: To make the contents of the next commit match (exactly 100%) the contents of some previous commit: `git read-tree --reset -u <hash>`. The `--reset` means "throw away the current index, replace with the target hash" and the `-u` means "update the work-tree to match the new index" (the `-u` is not technically required, but helps manage one's own sanity). This is similar to, but not identical to, `git checkout <hash> -- .` from the top level of the repository.

Comment: Whether this will achieve your final desired result, I'm not sure—you can work through the merge process now, though, following the graph to find the merge bases and look at what commits get diffed, to see if it's what you want.

Comment: _"Why do you care...?"_
`master` has been updated several times since development of `feature` began. The `integration` branch represents a specific server's configuration. I want to incorporate all of the updates to `master` into `integration` to bring it up to date and then overlay the  work in `feature`. Theoretically I could merge everything that was merged into master into `integration` individually but if there was a merge conflict along the way that I handle differently than how it was done before I no longer have an identical configuration.

Comment: Ah—but if you merged those pieces piecewise, you'd get a different (useful) graph. Note that you can also do a so-called "octopus merge" of multiple heads. Octopus merge cannot handle conflicts so that Git should just tell you that the merge cannot be done automatically, if that's the case. That might be the way to go for this particular case.